# Execute Hadoop Command from Java app using jsch remotely

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, jsch

Hi I'm triying execute any hadoop command like "hadoop fs -ls" throught a Java app remotely. I have my Java app in my local machine and Hadoop in a AWS server.

First I make a ssh connection and work. Also I can execute a linux command throught the java code but hadoop commands don´t show anything.

The current situation is the same as executing the command below.

```
//ssddff is a non-existent file
cd ssddff
```

I used the correct command.
Works command fine on server
But hadoop command callback not working and stop.

```
hadoop fs -ls
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls
```

```
ssh.getSSHResponse("hadoop fs -ls")
```

```
    public String getSSHResponse(String command) {
        StringBuilder response = null;
        try {
//          connectSSH();
            if(channelExec==null) {
                channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            }
            
            channelExec.setCommand(command);

            InputStream inputStream = channelExec.getInputStream();
            channelExec.connect();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int decodedLength;
            response = new StringBuilder();

            //when debugging, stop here
            while ((decodedLength = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
                response.append(new String(buffer, 0, decodedLength));

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            log.error("JSchException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

I try

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by connecting a new channel.

```
public String getSSHResponse(String command) {
    StringBuilder response = null;
    try {
        channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        
        channelExec.setCommand(command);

        InputStream inputStream = channelExec.getInputStream();
        channelExec.connect();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int decodedLength;
        response = new StringBuilder();
        //when debugging, stop here
        while ((decodedLength = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
            response.append(new String(buffer, 0, decodedLength));

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        log.error("JSchException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```